# Is there a way to save a gnome-shell session?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, session

I am running gnome-shell 3.2 on ubuntu 11.10

Is there a way of 'saving a session' in gnome shell - so that all the running applications are restored the next time I login?

I will ideally like to have a choice of saving the session or skipping it every time I log out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Session saving was removed during the development of Natty, so presumably, it's not in Oneiric either.**

---

> Here is a notice on what we decided during the Rally: we drop session
>   saving from natty in Ubuntu. The disablement is already effective in
>   natty.
>
> == Why removing it? ==
>
> We saw a lot of side effects during the previous cycles when we
>   started to use multiples session (like in UNE, desktop session and
>   such):
>   - the saved applications contains the list of all running application, including the window manager, the panel and suchâ€¦ Consequently, we
>   got a lot of patches and hack to avoid saving mutter, compiz,
>   metacity, and the panels in lucid and maverick, so that when someone
>   wanted to start a session, the required components from the session
>   will indeed been launched instead of the saved one.
>   - We tried last week to change the desktop order but it went quite wrong with a lot of settings and we had to revert it.
>   - In addition to that, session saving never really worked with all the default applications we have (for instance, openoffice, firefoxâ€¦)
>   and even with supported applications like gedit: the opened documents
>   weren't started again, making the feature quite useless.

The information above was derived from this source (visit this link for the full details): http://www.linux-archive.org/ubuntu-desktop/478109-gnome-session-saving-dropped-natty.html

---

Maybe you could suspend your computer instead of logging out? I believe that "saves" your session as well, as everything is there when you bring your computer back from being suspended.

Comment: Hibernation could be another alternative to suspending.