# how can i save automaticly the open apps on a session so that when i start ubuntu the apps not closed, open again automaticaly

Tags: gnome, shutdown, desktop-environments, session, 23.10

I want to be able to when i turn off the computer and the apps and programs not closed will be saved to open automatically when i start again ubuntu

i am using gnome on ubuntu 23.10.
But it would be nice to be able to do this on other desktop enviroments

how can i do, so that the system saves what apps are open when i shutdown or restart the laptop?an it is even possible to do this using ubuntu 23.10? on windows 11 i can do this on the same laptop

and on a final note suspension on ubuntu 23.10 uses lots of energy when on the same latop windows almost dont use any energy

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to save a gnome-shell session?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70625/is-there-a-way-to-save-a-gnome-shell-session)

Comment: No. GNOME removed this feature and will not add it back: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/1183 You could switch to Kubuntu if you need this feature

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make a script that opens terminal windows and executes commands in them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46627/how-can-i-make-a-script-that-opens-terminal-windows-and-executes-commands-in-the)

Comment: As far as suspension goes, Ubuntu doesn't really go to sleep and battery dies quickly. There are lots of questions on this posted already.

Comment: @DanielT Switching from GNOME to KDE would be rather drastic.

Comment: Perhaps, by describing both session and suspend, might you be thinking about hibernate a.k.a. suspend-to-disk? Otherwise, if opening a fixed set of programs, not whatever you had open last time, is fine, you can go with WinEunuuchs2Unix's link